# How to read a JSON in Unity to make an Array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a Visual Novel project in Unity.

To make the story, I used this website : https://twinery.org/ to make the script and the behaviour of buttons. Made a js script to transform this into a json and then tried to import it in Unity.

But here's the problem : I am totally lost when it comes to reading the JSON into Unity.

I have the class storing 1 "sequence" of the story :

```
public class DialogSequence : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string TextDialog; // The text that should be written in a box
    public string TextNameCharacter; // The name of the character on the display
    public Sprite SpriteCharacter; // The location where the image of the character is
    public Sprite SpriteBackground; // The location where the image of the background is
    public bool ChoiceMultiple; // If there is multiple choices or not
    public string[] TextChoice; // The text that should be written on the buttons (4 buttons at most)
    public string[] IndexChoice; // The index/key of the array where the next scene is stored at
}
```

The json looks like that :

```json
{
  "Story": [
    {
      "Title1": [
        {
          "TextDialog": "",
          "TextNameCharacter": "",
          "SpriteCharacter": "",
          "SpriteBackground": "",
          "ChoiceMultiple": false,
          "TextChoice": [
            "Next"
          ],
          "IndexChoice": [
            "Title2"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Title2": [
        {
          "TextDialog": "",
          "TextNameCharacter": "",
          "SpriteCharacter": "",
          "SpriteBackground": "",
          "ChoiceMultiple": false,
          "TexteChoice": [
            "Next"
          ],
          "IndexChoice": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    // [... + more than 180 objects]
  ]
}
```

I tried to use `[System.Serializable]` it doesn't work.
I tried to use JSONUtility with something like that `JsonUtility.FromJson<DialogSequence[]>(jsonString);` but it always outputted an error looking like that :

```
ArgumentException: Return type must represent an object type. Received an array.
UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) (at <b3935cb894394494ac117685fb6e14c7>:0)

UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[T] (System.String json) (at <b3935cb894394494ac117685fb6e14c7>:0)
MainGame.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/MainGame.cs:24)
```

Note that there will be a different story title for each one of the `Story[*].TitleX` properties.  Also, the property names aren't "Title1-2-...-180", I just changed it so that it's more readable and easier to understand.

How can I deserialize my JSON to an array of `DialogSequence` correctly?

Comment: 1) When you do `JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(jsonString)` your data model `T` must look like the **root** JSON object.  Your data model corresponds to some nested JSON object.  You need to fix that.  2) Do your *more than 180 objects* have different names for the `"Title1"` and ``"Title2"` properties?  E.g. is the last one ``"Title180"`

Comment: @Fildor `JsonUtility.FromJson` uses `[System.Serializable]`.  And I don't think it supports dictionaries, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3744182) for details.  I reckon querent would need to switch to Json.NET to deserialize to a dictionary.

Comment: I see. Why must it be so close but so different ... comment deleted.

Comment: @dbc yes, there is a different title for each one of them. The names aren't "Title1-2-...-180", I just changed it so that it's more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: @JeanMahmoud - OK, got it.  Then I believe you will need to Unity's official build of Newtonsoft from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2/manual/index.html).  Will that be a problem?

Comment: @dbc No problem, I'll try this and come back later, tysm

Comment: As the error says, yor JSON structure is not JSON array but a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

When you deserialize from JSON to some type `T`, no matter which serializer you use, the data model for `T` must match the schema of the **root JSON container**.  In your case the root JSON container looks like:

```json
{
  "Story": [
    {
      "TitleX": [ /* An array of DialogSequence objects */ ]
    }
    // Additional Story objects with TitleX properties.
  ]
}
```

Where the `"TitleX"` names will vary at runtime.  As you can see this does not correspond to an array of `DialogSequence` objects.

In order to deserialize this, your root data model needs to look like:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<DialogSequence>>> Story { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Now, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3744182) by [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer), `JsonUtility` does not support dictionaries, so you will need to install Unity's official Json.NET build [com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2/manual/index.html) by adding `com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json` via the package manager.

Having done so, you can now deserialize and project to an array of `DialogSequence` objects as follows:

```
var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);

DialogSequence [] dialogs = 
    root.Story.SelectMany(d => d.Values).SelectMany(v => v).ToArray();
```

You **may** also need to modify `DialogSequence` and change your `Sprite` properties to strings, then load the actual sprites after deserialization completes:

```
public class DialogSequence : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Changed from Sprite to string
    public string SpriteCharacter; // The location where the image of the character is
    // Changed from Sprite to string
    public string SpriteBackground; // The location where the image of the background is
```

In your JSON these properties are stored as strings, so either your serialized data model needs to match that, or you need to write a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) to handle the conversion. See e.g. [How to load sprite from JSON?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115840/158277).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gDCTk1).